# "Es" in a sentence

Tags: expression

> Manche Menschen lernen **es** nie.

vs

> Manche Menschen lernen nie.

Is "es" required in this case? Are there expressions that must have "es" in their structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Manche Menschen lernen **es** nie.

... refers to something that ”manche Menschen” never learn. As an example: ”Manche Menschen lernen nie zu kochen”. So ”es” can be cocking, mathematics or something else, but in this example it isn‘t defined.

> Manche Menschen lernen nie.

... doesn't refer to anything specific either. It generalized, that some people (manche Menschen) never learn. But in this sentence you don‘t say, what this ”some people” never learn.

Comment: One would expect a sentence like "Manche Menschen lernen es nie" to be preceded by a sentence which contains the information what "es" refers to. For example: "Karl hat schon wieder das Schitzel anbrennen lassen. Manche Menschen lernen es nie."